# CodeIgniter only shows default controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

When testing the website on my local machine everything worked fine, but after uploading it only the default controller shows.

This is my setup:

url:
http://devilmay88.bplaced.net/live-access/

Folder structure:

```
/live-access
   /application
   /system
   /assets
```

config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://devilmay88.bplaced.net/live-access/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['assets/(:any)'] = 'assets/$1';
$route['login'] = 'Login';
```

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /live-access   
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /live-access/index.php?/{controller}/{method}/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The .htaccess file is in the live-access folder and since I got an error while testing other content, it seems to be interpreted. When I change the uri_protocol all I get is 404. And the codeIgniter version is 3.0.6.

Does anybody see what's wrong here?

I just found that uri_string() returns an empty string (also with the so far suggested .htaccess changes).

Comment: Can you provide a sample URL that works on your local environment, as well as the related URL that doesn't work on your hosting environment?

Comment: Usually people put trailing slash at the end of `RewriteBase /live-access/`. With that on mind, you don't need leading slash in `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/{controller}/{method}/$1 [L]`. Also I think repeating directory name `live-access` is sufficient. Try with removing q mark too. As tested, I'd say it's up to last one I just proposed.

Comment: Lower case it should be `$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';`

Comment: Make sure all the other controllers files names and class have first letter only upper case http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

Comment: Controllers and controller files have their first letter in upper case. I tried the changes wolfgang1983 and Tpojka suggest, but still nothing changes. Actually on my local environment I worked without .htaccess, I suspected that this didn't work online because of the subfolder-structure (but I tried and it didn't work).

Comment: For example the url localhost/index.php/login worked, but http://devilmay88.bplaced.net/live-access/index.php/login does not.

Answer (score 0):

try something simpler for your htaccess like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(application) - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /live-access/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

also you aren't telling us - what other route or url have you tried? what error did you get?

Comment: Tried it, but no changes. I don't recall everything I tried, basically everything I found online on that topic. I get a 500 error with 'Options +FollowSymLinks', nothing else seems to have an effect.

Comment: Upload a new fresh copy of codeigniter, confirm it works, then test that. If it still does not work then contact your hosting company. The subdomain might be an issue.